# How to sum multiple SQL queries together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run multiple queries on multiple tables-  similar to "select count(*) from TableA where x=1" per table.

What I'd like to do, is get all of the count(*) values that are returned and sum them into a single value...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to do this in SQL?  Or in your calling language - little more information would be useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select sum(individual_counts) from
(
  select count(*) as individual_counts from TableA where x = 1
    union all
  select count(*) from TableB where x = 2
....
) as temp_table_name
```

you normally only need the alias on the first select when using a union.

Comment: That won't work if there are any counts that are the same. The duplicates won't get included. Doing `UNION ALL` should work though.

Comment: @Josh: you're quite right: I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but maybe:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA)+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB)
```